# UITableView, Separator color where to set?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have added a `UITableView` in IB and set the "delegate" and "datasource" and all is working well. What I wanted to do next was change the separator color, but the only way I could find to do this was to add the method to one of the delegate callbacks, is there a better place I should put this?

I don't have this at the moment but I was thinking that maybe I need to add an "iVar" from my controller that I can link to the `UITableView` in IB and then set separator color in the `viewDidload`?

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    return 65;
}
```

Comment: Adding the variable and hooking it up in IB is how I've always done it.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. I was doing a tutorial they did not use and iVar, they just relied on the delegate and datasource callbacks. However they never accessed the separator color so maybe thats why.

Answer (score 361, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor myColor]];
}
```

You'll need the `self.` to access it, remember.

**Swift 4.2**

```
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: Hi Helen, does that access it without the need to add a @property, it looks like it does?

Comment: This is true.  You are subclassing UITableViewController, which declares it as a property.  It therefore inherits the accessor/setter methods of the superclass, so you can set it accordingly.  However, you cannot access the instance variable directly (probably a good thing).  The reason why you can set it in a delegate method is because it is a parameter to the method called.

Comment: Or if you like: self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor;

Comment: Not particularly part of the answer, but adding `[super viewDidLoad];` to the code snippet would be nice.

Comment: This worked, but it has more cells than needed. If I have 4 cells, how do I not have a ton of extra empty cells below?

Answer (score 59):

Now you should be able to do it directly in the IB.

Not sure though, if this was available when the question was posted originally.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

**Swift** version:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Assign your color to this property, for example here we assign the red color.
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Comment: This shows me an error `'separatorColor' is unavailable` on tvOS.

Answer (score 12):

Try ***+ (instancetype)appearance*** of UITableView:

*Objective-C:*

```
[[UITableView appearance] setSeparatorColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; // set your desired colour in place of "[UIColor blackColor]"
```

*Swift 3.0:*

```
UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = UIColor.black // set your desired colour in place of "UIColor.black"
```

**Note:** Change will reflect to all tables used in application.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3, xcode version 8.3.2, storyboard->choose your table View->inspector->Separator.

[image: Swift 3, xcode version 8.3.2]

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to set the same color to every separator and it is opaque you can use:

```
 self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

If you want to use different colors for the separators or clear the separator color or use a color with alpha.

BE CAREFUL: You have to know that there is a backgroundView in the separator that has a default color.

To change it you can use this functions:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        if(view.isKindOfClass(UITableViewHeaderFooterView)){
            var headerView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView;
            headerView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = myColor

           //Other colors you can change here
           // headerView.backgroundColor = myColor
           // headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = myColor
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        if(view.isKindOfClass(UITableViewHeaderFooterView)){
            var footerView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView;
            footerView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = myColor
           //Other colors you can change here
           //footerView.backgroundColor = myColor
           //footerView.contentView.backgroundColor = myColor
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This shows me an error `'separatorColor' is unavailable` on tvOS.

Comment: tvos has not all features of ios.