# How to set color for separator for UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

How I can set the color of separator of sections?
I set all posible colors to "f5f5f5", but the separator is "ededed".
Why it can be?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813068/uitableview-change-section-header-color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView, Separator color where to set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364859/uitableview-separator-color-where-to-set)

Answer (score 1):

**Objective c**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {     
  [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 }
```

**Swift**

```
func viewDidLoad()
{
 self.tableview.separatorColor = UIColor.redColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Extension to set a Shadow in your `UITableVIewCell`

```
extension UIView {
public func applyShadow(
    withOpacity opacity: Float = 0.4,
                offset: CGSize = CGSizeMake(2.0, 0.5),
                radius: CGFloat = 3.0) -> Void {

    self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    self.layer.shadowOffset = offset
    self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
}
```

You can use this extension. `cell.applyShadow()`

Answer (score 0):

To change color of Separator:

`self.tableview.separatorColor = UIColor.redColor`

I hope it helps!